# gcc with cygwin 64 installing rbenv

Tags: gcc, cygwin, rbenv

Since cygwin has now split into 32 and 64 bit versions, I haven't been able to find a working solution for installing ruby versions with rbenv and ruby-build (a la https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installation ), which requires gcc to compile the native extensions.

My machine is Win7 64-bit, and I've now installed the 64-bit cygwin via setup-x86_64.exe and a vanilla installation of rbenv. The of gcc options are now:

- cygwin32-gcc
- gcc
- mingw-gcc
- mingw64-i686-gcc
- mingw64-x86_64-gcc

Each of these has multiple subcategories, but for my needs I took only the corresponding core and g++ options. I've tried each in turn via

```
export CC=/bin/<gcc-executable>
rbenv install 1.9.3-p0
```

This begins by downloading and attempting to compile yaml. For all but the last of these, the `configure` phase fails with e.g.

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/ruby-build.20131206180232.7988/yaml-0.1.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

(I can dig up those logs if necessary, but I take that to mean that it can't compile an executable for this architechture).

The last one (mingw64-x86_64-gcc) seemed the most promising. It completes the `configure` phase, but it still fails to compile the yaml module (first module it tries) with the log below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't think this is an rbenv issue, but rather the symptom of my misconfiguration of gcc.

Full log here:
http://pastebin.com/WCukkAWu

But the relevant bits around the failure are:

```
run-parser.o: In function `main':
/tmp/ruby-build.20131206180255.6208/yaml-0.1.4/tests/run-parser.c:16: undefined reference to `__imp_yaml_parser_parse'
/tmp/ruby-build.20131206180255.6208/yaml-0.1.4/tests/run-parser.c:49: undefined reference to `__imp_yaml_event_delete'
/tmp/ruby-build.20131206180255.6208/yaml-0.1.4/tests/run-parser.c:36: undefined reference to `__imp_yaml_parser_initialize'
/tmp/ruby-build.20131206180255.6208/yaml-0.1.4/tests/run-parser.c:38: undefined reference to `__imp_yaml_parser_set_input_file'
/tmp/ruby-build.20131206180255.6208/yaml-0.1.4/tests/run-parser.c:54: undefined reference to `__imp_yaml_parser_delete'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:320: recipe for target 'run-parser.exe' failed
```